# Concavity of logistic growth equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, biology

I was given the logistic growth equation $\frac{dN}{dt}=rN(1-\frac{N}{K})$ with $N(0)=N_o$.

I found the solution of this logistic equation: $N(t)=\frac{K}{\frac{K-N_o}{N_o}e^{-rt}+1}$.

Then, I was asked to show that the graph is concave up for $N_o < N < \frac{K}{2}$ and $N_o > K$ and that it is concave down for $\frac{K}{2} < N < K$.

I started by finding the first derivative of $N(t)$, however it is very messy and seems like there should be a more efficient way.

Any hint is appreciated!

Comment: You have to look at the sign of the second derivative to determine if it is concave up or down. You can't find the second derivative explicitly without solving the equation.

Comment: Are you saying that I have to find the second derivative of N(t)?

Comment: Yes, and see the sign of it in the region of interest.

Comment: Thank you, I'll get started on that now :)

Comment: $$\frac{d^2N}{dt^2}=r(1-\frac{N}{K})\frac{dN}{dt}+rN(-\frac{1}{K}\frac{dN}{dt})$$ Now substitute $dN/dt$ and $N$

Comment: @PiyushDivyanakar " You can't find the second derivative explicitly without solving the equation" This is quite wrong, *as your last comment shows*.

Comment: @Did but in order to get the relation to the form of explicit function of $t$ you do need the explicit expression of $N(t)$

Comment: @PiyushDivyanakar "To get the relation to the form of explicit function of $t$" is not needed. Actually the whole idea of the exercise is to avoid this explicit formula.

Comment: @Did yes right, my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{dN}{dt}=rN(1-\frac{N}{K})\\N'=rN(1-\frac{1}{k}N)\\\text{ take derivative }\\N''=r(1-\frac{1}{k}N).N'+rN(0-\frac{1}{k}).N' \\\text{ plug  N'}\\
N''=r(1-\frac{1}{k}N).rN(1-\frac{1}{k}N)+rN(0-\frac{1}{k}).rN(1-\frac{1}{k}N)=\\r^2N(1-\frac{1}{k}N)((1-\frac{1}{k}N)+N(0-\frac{1}{k}))=
\\r^2N(1-\frac{1}{k}N)(1-\frac{2}{k}N)=\\\frac{r^2}{k^2}N(k-N)(K-2N)$$